# React componentWillReceiveProps check not working if API responds too quick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React container component which on page load dispatches an action (using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method). The action calls an API, a successful API call results in the data being added to my Redux store via a reducer.

I have some other API's which require data from the response of the initial  API call. I have these in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and I'm comparing `this.props` against `nextProps` to work out whether I have the data ready to call the API's.

90% of the time this code works and the API calls inside of `componentWillReceiveProps` are successfully called, but the other 10% of the API's don't get called because the code inside of the if statement which compares `this.props` to `nextProps` doesn't execute.

From testing I think I've found the issue... If the initial API call returns fast enough, the very first time `componentWillReceiveProps` is called `this.props` is already populated with data from the API call rather than returning my initial state, at which point the if statement doesn't execute.

What is the best way of bulletproofing this?

```
<Route
  path={'Content/:id'}
  component={DrillPage}
/>

class DrillPage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getLoggedInUser();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(nextProps);

    // Don't fire if user isn't logged in
    if (this.props.loggedInUser.id !== nextProps.loggedInUser.id) {
      this.props.actions.isFavourite(this.props.content.id, this.props.content.type);
      this.props.actions.doIFollow([this.props.content.author.id]);
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    contentId: ownProps.params.id,
    loggedInUser: state.loggedInUser,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, contentActions, userActions), dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DrillPage);
```

Comment: You can call the second api from the first api call result

Comment: You can move the API call to `componentWillMount` hook and ensure that `DrillPage`s parent component is re-rendered with correct data so that it can send correct props to `DrillPage`.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi DrillPage is the parent component.

Comment: Can you please try replacing `Object.assign({}, contentActions, userActions)` with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({contentActions, userActions}))`?

Comment: Any luck with the above change?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try a solution without using the React lifecycle and handle your logic in your `sagas` since, as I understand you're using `componentWillReceiveProps` to fire other API calls only if you have a `userId`

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would work? I'm not using `sagas`, I'm using `redux-thunk`.

Comment: Something like this in your action
   return fetch('yourUrl', opts)
      .then(resp => {
         if (resp.id) {
           return fetch('yourNewUrl', opts);
        } 
        return resp;
       });

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom middleware for Redux that calls the API on an action dispatch from your component. Then it would directly modify the state and have no dependence on the component other than the initial dispatch.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would work? I'm already calling the API from an action dispatch in my component (I'm doing `mapDispatchToProps`), therefore `this.props.actions.getLoggedInUser();` is calling the API and directly modifying state.